# Method return type polymorphism

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I have 4 C# classes; `Job`, `BuildJob`, `JobFactory` and `BuildJobfactory`. Below are the MVPs of each class.

```
public class Job {

}

public abstract class JobFactory {
    public abstract List<Job> GetJobs(List<B> bs);
}

public class BuildJob : Job {
    A a;
    B b;

    public BuildJob(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

}

public class BuildJobFactory : JobFactory {
    A a;

    public override List<Job> GetJobs(List<B> bs) {
        return bs.ConvertAll(b => new BuildJob(a, b));
    }

}
```

`JobFactory` is used to create a load of jobs from a list of `B` instances, and the way that those jobs are constructed will depend on their types (`BuildJob`, `DestroyJob` et.c) so this has to be left to a factory class. As I come from a Java background, I assumed that returning a `List<BuildJob>` from a method whose return type is declared as `List<Job>` would be fine, as `BuildJob` extends `Job`, but this does not work in C#.

To alleviate this, I then tried generics so the modified classes looked like so.

```
public abstract class JobFactory<T> where T : Job, new() {
    public abstract List<T> GetJobs(List<B> bs);
}

public class BuildJobFactory : JobFactory<BuildJob> {
    A a;

    public override List<BuildJob> GetJobs(List<B> bs) {
        return bs.ConvertAll(b => new BuildJob(a, b));
    }

}
```

I tried to make a variable of type `JobFactory` without a generic declaration (`Jobfactory currentJobFactory;`) as it will be unknown at compile time, since at runtime the variable will be assigned to some instance of some class that extends `JobFactory` with some unknown generic, but this does not work as it does in Java.

How could I solve one of these problems?

Comment: Can I ask how you would use a `JobFactory<BuildJob>`? Because personally I don't see an issue with the second example, but the only issue that you'll encounter would be if you wanted a single place to build a `Job` say a `JobBuilder`, but I don't know if this is your use case?

Comment: Use IEnumerable<T> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654055.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public override List<Job> GetJobs(List<B> bs) {
   return bs.Select(b => new BuildJob(a, b)).Cast<Job>().ToList();
}
```

Edit: If `Select()` is unavailable, you probably need to add the following to the beginning of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

This will instruct the compiler to search for extension methods (which `Select()` is one of) in the `System.Linq` namespace.

What this is doing:

`bs.Select()` iterates over the `bs` list, executing the lambda on each one, resulting in an `IEnumerable<BuildJob>`.  `.Cast<Job>()` converts that to an `IEnumerable<Job>`, and finally, `.ToList()` converts the `IEnumerable<Job>` to a `List<Job>`.

All that said, I would consider changing the signatures of your methods to  return `IEnumerable<Job>`, which would remove the need for the `.Cast<Job>().ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but unfortunately I'm using Unity whose version of `List` doesn't have the `Select` method.

Comment: I added to my answer, also, but try adding `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a List of BuildJobs as a List of Jobs, but you can add a BuildJob to a List of Jobs.

For Example:

```
    public override List<Job> GetJobs(List<B> bs) {
        List<Job> temp = new List<Job>();
        foreach (var b in bs) {
            temp.Add(new BuildJob(new A(), b));
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Not as slick and inline as a LINQ statement, but functional.

I agree with the rest that IEnumerable is a better return type, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IEnumerable<T>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` as both of these interfaces support covariance.  It's considered bad practise to return concrete collection types anyway because it exposes lots of implementation details.

Choose `IEnumerable<T>` if you want deferred exceution and `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` if you don't.

```
public class Job 
{ }

public abstract class JobFactory 
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<Job> GetJobs(IEnumerable<B> bs);
}

public class BuildJob : Job 
{
    A a;
    B b;

    public BuildJob(A a, B b) 
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

}

public class BuildJobFactory : JobFactory 
{
    A a;

    public override IEnumerable<Job> GetJobs(IEnumerable<B> bs) 
    {
        return bs.Select(b => new BuildJob(a, b));
    }

}
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt654055.aspx for more info on covariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 0):

Generics in C# are much more strict than they are in Java.  You can't leave out the generic and default to the interpretation that everything is an `Object`.  However, you can use [Covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) to work around the situation.

If you change the generic so that it looks like this:

```
public abstract class JobFactory<out T>
    where T : Job, new()
{
    public abstract List<T> GetJobs(List<B> bs);
}
```

Then you have the ability to freely cast the `JobFactory<BuildJob>` to `JobFactory<Job>` without issue.  This is the way `IEnumerable<out T>` is defined.  You can build the logic for your core code around the base assumption, but specialize things further down the line.

Basically it means you can do this:

```
 JobFactory<BuildJob> derivedFactory = new JobFactory<BuildJob>();
 JobFactory<Job> baseFactory = derivedFactory;
```

Or more directly you can use code that looks like this:

```
 public class Container
 {
     public JobFactory<Job> Factory { get; set; }
 }
```

and later on assign that property like this:

```
 Container myContainer = new Container {
     Factory = new JobFactory<BuildJob>()
 };
```

Comment: I have tried this but get the error "The type parameter T must be invariantly valid on JobFactory<T>.GetJobs(List<B>). T is covariant" and I don't quite understand it.

Comment: You can't assign covariance to abstract classes, you'd have to create an interface instead.

Comment: Even if it were an interface, covariance wouldn't work with `List` because `List` is a concrete class (nor would it work with `IList` because it's not covariant).

Comment: I did actually make it an interface with the following header `public interface JobFactory<out T> where T : Job, new() {`